How to add `not-found` page in different route group level in next js 14
This is my folder structure:
app
├── (app1)
│    └── ekko 
│       ├── layout.tsx
│       ├── not-found.tsx
│       └── page.tsx
│
└── (admin)
│    └── admin
│       ├── layout.tsx
│       ├── not-found.tsx
│       └── page.tsx
│
└── layout.tsx

I have not-found.tsx for each Route Group, When I visit wrong pathname e.g. /admin/whatever, I expect it to render /admin/not-found.tsx but instead it renders the default 404 page.

I expect to get the specified Not Found page when navigating to /ekko/wrong-params

and when user hit admi/wrong-params:

i want when the user hit ekko/wrong-params
then show this not found page:

and when user hit admi/wrong-params:


not-found.tsx file in Next.js catches notFound() throws in only one segment level.
If you execute notFound() in /admin/page.tsx, it will render /admin/not-found.tsx
// admin/page.tsx

import {notFound} from "next/navigation";

export default function AdminPage() {
  const user = await getSession();
  if (!user || user.role !== "ADMIN") notFound();
  // ...
}

It doesn't catch all nested routes.
EXCEPT the root app/not-found.tsx. In addition to catching notFound() calls in app/page.tsx, it will be used as a fallback for 404 requests starting from Next.js@13.3.0. The reason you see the default 404 instead of your not-found.tsx files, is because Next.js under-the-hood make app/not-found.js if there is no any.
How to solve?
You can achieve your requirement by Catch All routes with the [...name] format. Just move your */not-found.tsx content to */[...anyName]/page.tsx like this:
app
├── (app1)
│    └── ekko 
│       ├── layout.tsx
│       ├── [...anyNotFound]/page.tsx
│       └── page.tsx
│
└── (admin)
│    └── admin
│       ├── layout.tsx
│       ├── [...catchAll]/page.tsx
│       └── page.tsx
│
└── layout.tsx

In the catch all segments, you have access to the URL.
// [...name]/page.tsx

interface Props {
  params: {
    name: string[]
  }
}

export default function name({ params }: Props) {
  return <div>The {params.name.join("/")} is not found</div>
}


Error: You cannot have two parallel pages that resolve to the same path

I need more details, please create a new question and reply the link here. Please run npx tree-cli and share the output in the question
